# What does :-> mean in a haskell type specification

Tags: haskell

I've seen this in a few places:

```
data T = T a :-> b
```

Notably in quickcheck we have

```
data Fun a b = Fun (a :-> b, b) (a -> b)
```

What is the `:->` and how does it differ from `->`?

Comment: Could you please post the addition as an aswer? It's great to answer your own questions, tough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Operators beginning with a colon is a constructor or type name. In this case it is a type name for a data type specific to quickcheck, but in general the symbol :-> could be used for any constructor or type name as you like (it's not part of the language proper).

[The definition of :-> in quickcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.1.0.3/doc/html/src/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html#%3a-%3E):

```
-- the type of possibly partial concrete functions
data a :-> c where
  Pair  :: (a :-> (b :-> c)) -> ((a,b) :-> c)
  (:+:) :: (a :-> c) -> (b :-> c) -> (Either a b :-> c)
  Unit  :: c -> (() :-> c)
  Nil   :: a :-> c
  Table :: Eq a => [(a,c)] -> (a :-> c)
  Map   :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b :-> c) -> (a :-> c)
```

Answer (score 5):

Answered my own question: first saw this as

```
data Edge = i :-> i
```

`:->` is of course the constructor.